# DictionaryEntry to user object

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, dictionary, properties

I have a custom user object class appuser

```
   public class appuser
    {
        public Int32 ID { get; set; }
        public Int32 ipamuserID { get; set; }
        public Int32 appID { get; set; }
        public Int32 roleID { get; set; }
        public Int16 departmenttypeID { get; set; }
        public generaluse.historycrumb recordcrumb { get; set; }

        public appuser() { }
        public appuser(DataRow dr)
        {
            ID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["AppUserID"].ToString());
            ipamuserID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["IpamUserID"].ToString());
            appID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["AppID"].ToString());
            roleID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["AppRoleID"].ToString());
            departmenttypeID = Convert.ToInt16(dr["AppDepartmentTypeID"].ToString());
            recordcrumb = new generaluse.historycrumb(dr);
        }
        public void appuserfill(DictionaryEntry de, ref appuser _au)
        {
            //Search for key in appuser given by de and set appuser property to de.value
        }
    }
```

How do I set the property within the appuser object that is passed as the key in the DictionaryEntry without knowing what the key initially is?

for example: de.key = ipamuserID, dynamically find the property within _au and set the value = de.value?

Comment: May be, _Reflection_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, you can use reflection, but it's not a good 
solution - trying to write into arbitrary properties.
The solution with reflection could be like this one:

```
//Search for key in appuser given by de and set appuser property to de.value
public void appuserfill(DictionaryEntry de, ref appuser _au) { // <- There's no need in "ref"
  if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null, de))
    throw new ArgumentNullException("de");
  else if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null, _au))
    throw new ArgumentNullException("_au");

  PropertyInfo pInfo = _au.GetType().GetProperty(de.Key.ToString(), BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);

  if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null, pInfo))
    throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("Property {0} is not found.", de.Key.ToString()), "de");
  else if (!pInfo.CanWrite)
    throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("Property {0} can't be written.", de.Key.ToString()), "de");

  pInfo.SetValue(_au, de.Value);
}
```